# Bash - Date manipulation and join

Tags: python, bash, csv, join

I have two CSV files that I would like to merge using the `DATE` (CSV 1) and `pickup_datetime` (CSV 2).

**CSV 1: Weather.csv (45KB ~ 365 rows)**

```
head -3 Weather.csv 
STATION,STATION_NAME,ELEVATION,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,DATE,PRCP,SNWD,SNOW,TMAX,TMIN,AWND,WDF2,WSF2
GHCND:USW00094728,NEW YORK CENTRAL PARK OBS BELVEDERE TOWER NY US,39.6,40.77889,-73.96917,20130101,0,0,0,44,-33,31,310,67
GHCND:USW00094728,NEW YORK CENTRAL PARK OBS BELVEDERE TOWER NY US,39.6,40.77889,-73.96917,20130102,0,0,0,6,-56,26,310,67
```

**CSV 2: Final_Data_1.csv (250MB ~ 1.5M rows)**

```
head -3 final_data_1.csv 
medallion,hack_license,vendor_id_x,rate_code,store_and_fwd_flag,pickup_datetime,dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_time_in_secs,trip_distance,pickup_longitude,pickup_latitude,dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude,vendor_id_y,payment_type,fare_amount,surcharge,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,total_amount
DFD2202EE08F7A8DC9A57B02ACB81FE2,51EE87E3205C985EF8431D850C786310,CMT,1,N,2013-01-01 23:54:15,2013-01-01 23:58:20,2,244,0.7,-73.974602,40.759945,-73.984734,40.759388,CMT,CSH,5.0,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.0,6.0
237F49C3ECC11F5024B254268F054384,93C363DDF8ED9385D65FAD07CE3F5F07,CMT,1,N,2013-01-01 07:35:47,2013-01-01 07:46:00,1,612,2.3,-73.98850999999999,40.774307,-73.981094,40.755325,CMT,CSH,10.0,0.0,0.5,0.0,0.0,10.5
```

How do I manipulate the date column in both CSV files and merge it to get one file with columns of `Final_Data_1.csv` coming before `Weather.csv`?

Comment: How would you find out which line of FinalData is to be merged into which of Weather? So, which is the id to link them together?

Comment: Since you are using the Python tag, have you tried the Python csv module?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Well, final_data will have approximately 50,000 rows for 2013-01-01. So it needs to replicate the corresponding values in weather.csv into the final_data.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to be using Bash, a good way in Python would be to use pandas, something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('weather.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('final.csv')
#format the date columns so they match up
df3 = pd.merge(df2,df1, on='date_formatted')
```